# How to reorder expression elements in a string based on rules of SCIM filter precedence?

Tags: java

I need to implement (at least partially) SCIM Filtering specification.
My strategy was to recursively go through the string and build binary tree of expression objects, with the first expression to be evaluated as the root.
However, I was not able to effectively process expressions with parentheses while doing the tree walk. Therefor, I decided to get rid of parentheses first, which would require placing all elements of the expression in the correct order according to SCIM Filtering rules of precedence, which are:

1. Expression in parentheses
2. NOT
3. AND
4. OR

So a string `A and (B or (C))` after reordering is transformed into `C or B and A` (don't mind the capital letters. These are used to substitute actual SCIM filtering expressions).

I've tried to parse the filter string by dividing it with `split()` but this approach is very clumsy, since I need to track opening and closing parentheses. What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Your rewrite changes the meaning, using commonly-accepted rules of precedence.  'C or B and A' means 'C or (B and A)'.  And what are you going to do with '(A or B) and (C or D)'?  If you want a parenthesis-free form, consider reverse polish.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE]. Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, clarifies what you want to achieve.